# Discrepancy between iPhone's reported focal length and values in AVCaptureDevice.Format

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, avfoundation

To work out the 35mm equivalent focal length of an iPhone camera I have the following function.

```
func get35mmEquivalentFocalLength(format : AVCaptureDevice.Format) -> Float {
    // get reported field of view. Documentation says this is the horizontal field of view
    var fov = format.videoFieldOfView
    // convert to radians
    fov *= Float.pi/180.0
    // angle and opposite of right angle triangle are half the fov and half the width of 
    // 35mm film (ie 18mm). The adjacent value of the right angle triangle is the equivalent 
    // focal length. Using some right angle triangle math you can work out focal length
    let focalLen = 18 / tan(fov/2)
    return focalLen
}
```

The iPhone 7 has a videoFieldOfView of just under 60 degrees this returns an equivalent focal length to be just over 31mm. This is not the value Apple report as the equivalent focal length in their press. They report 28mm. I compared the camera with a number of other cameras and the iPhone 7 camera does look to have a 28mm equivalent lens so what is going wrong with the calculations above?

Comment: It looks like format.videoFieldOfView is the field of view when recording video which is smaller than when taken stills.